# Dependabot failed to update your dependencies because there was an error parsing the package.json found at /package.json

Tags: react-native, github-actions, dependabot

I have the Dependabot GitHub action enabled in my **React Native** app's repository but for some reason, it won't automatically update. I have 2 dependencies that won't:
[xmldon 0.5.0 and node-fetch 2.6.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiPNi.png)

I keep getting this error when I try to Create Dependabot security update:

```
Dependabot failed to update your dependencies because there was an error parsing the package.json found at /package.json.

Dependabot encountered the following error:

Dependabot::DependencyFileNotParseable
```

Also, I shouldn't have to manually create a dependabot security updates since my github action should automate it, which looks like this:

```
# To get started with Dependabot version updates, you'll need to specify which
# package ecosystems to update and where the package manifests are located.
# Please see the documentation for all configuration options:
# https://help.github.com/github/administering-a-repository/configuration-options-for-dependency-updates

version: 2
updates:
  # Maintain dependencies for GitHub Actions
  - package-ecosystem: "github-actions"
    directory: "/"
    schedule:
      interval: "weekly"

  # Maintain dependencies for npm
  - package-ecosystem: "npm"
    directory: "/"
    schedule:
      interval: "weekly"
 
  # Maintain dependencies for Python files in requirements.txt
  - package-ecosystem: "pip"
    directory: "/"
    schedule:
      interval: "weekly"
```

Route: **my-app/.github/dependabot.yml**

Am I missing something here? I enabled this the exact same way for my website, which is written in **React.js**, and it's working perfectly.

Comment: did you find any solution to this ?